# Delete specific columns with NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:50, B = 11:60, c = 21:70)
head(df)
df.final <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(cc) cc[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))
```

I want to delete the columns that its last 5 values ​​are not filled by NA. That is, only the columns that has values in the rows from 46 to 50 remain. the columns which the last 5 values has one or more NA´s will be deleted.

Is it possible do this with dplyr?

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::select()` accepts integer column positions. We can use that to achieve this -

```
result <- df.final %>% select(., which(!is.na(colSums(tail(., 5)))))
head(result)
   A  B
1  1 11
2  2 NA
3  3 13
4 NA 14
5  5 15
6 NA 16
```

Comment: Do check out solution by @Yuri-M-Dias. That'll probably be faster for large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

Shree beat me to it, but it might come in handy:

```
> df.final %>% tail
    A  B  c
45 45 55 65
46 46 NA 66
47 47 57 67
48 NA 58 68
49 NA 59 69
50 NA 60 NA

> df.final %>%
+     select_if(~ !any(is.na(tail(., n = 1)))) %>%
+     tail()
    B
45 55
46 NA
47 57                                                           
48 58                                                          
49 59                                                            
50 60
```

Just change the `n` above to the number of last NAs that you want.